# Symfony Registration form not being rendered

Tags: php, symfony

I have been following along with the tutorial book on the symfony site and I have been trying to get a registration form going without using FOS, just so that I get a handle of how it all works.

I followed along with the steps here: 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#security-crete-user-entity
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html

However when I run it and I go to /register. I do not get a form rendered but instead a http login appears asking for a username and password. However, despite what I enter it will keep repeating itself and it will not render the form.

Comment: read http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html about http_basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your app/config/security.yml .
If you use this [article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#security-crete-user-entity) you must have this security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
    providers:
        our_db_provider:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle:User
                property: username
                # if you're using multiple entity managers
                # manager_name: customer

    firewalls:
        default:
            pattern:    ^/
            http_basic: ~
            provider: our_db_provider
```

It means that all routes are protected by http basic auth. You should add access controls to your security.yml

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your route in the routing.yml. That's not said in these tutorials.

```
# app/config/routing.yml

# ...

register:
    pattern:   /register
    defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Security:register }
```